# Rails and Devise gem: How do I change where my web app redirects to after a failed login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

how do I change where my web app redirects to after a failed login?  I've been digging through the Devise wiki looking for this and all I can find is the code to change where the app redirects to after a successful sign in, sign out, and sign up.  But when I test my app and I type in the wrong password, it takes me to an error page that reads...

```
No route matches {:controller=>"devise/projects"}
```

That route of course doesn't exist and I have no idea why it's trying to redirect there and I'd like to change where Devise redirects to after a failed login.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at devise Session controller:

```
class Devise::SessionsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    resource = build_resource
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    respond_with_navigational(resource, stub_options(resource)){ render_with_scope :new }
  end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
 end
```

Authentication happens there with warden:

```
 resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
```

It's says when auth failed, render action :new from sessions controller, which rendered login form. Make sure you does not override this in your custom devise inherited controller. Or maybe try to override it.